# if i configure Jenkins to run test using scripts maintained in a github repo, does it import the scripts in the local jenkins workspace directory

Tags: java, maven, jenkins, testng

if i configure Jenkins to run test using scripts maintained in a github repo, does it import the scripts in the local jenkins workspace directory and then run tests on those scripts

I searched in google, but could not find a definitive answer.

Jenkins version that i am using -Version 2.0. 
Type of Job - Freestyle project
Tests are configured to run using build step - mvn test. Test scripts are webdriver java using TestNG framework

I have just configured the job yet, but not yet try to run. Just want to know how jenkins supposed to run test in such a configuration

Comment: Why don't to you just run it and see what happens?

Comment: @StephenKing, ya i m gonna do that

Answer (score 0):

Jenkins clones a copy of the github repo on the local jenkins workspace and would run all the test cases on the cloned code.